# Filter arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array: `[[True], [False], [True]]`. If I would want this array to filter my existing array, e.g `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` should get filtered to `[[1,2],[5,6]]`, what is the correct way to do this?

A simple `a[b]` indexing gives the error: `boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1`

Comment: Use `a[b.ravel()]`.

Comment: Wow. That was quick. Thanks. It works! :) Please vote to close this question as a duplicate if you find one. I couldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to get the array `[[True], [False], [True]]` into shape `[True, False, True]`, so that it works for indexing the rows of the other array. As Divakar said,  [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel) does this; in general it flattens any array to a 1D array. Another option is [`squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) which removes the dimensions with size 1 but leaves the  other dimensions as they were,

Answer (score 1):

## Use [`.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel)...

From the documentation, `ravel` will:

> Return a contiguous flattened array.

So if we have your `b` `array`:

```
b = np.array([[True], [False], [True]])
```

we can take the `boolean` values out of their `sub-arrays` with:

```
b.ravel()
```

which gives:

```
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

So then, we can simply use `b.ravel()` as a mask for `a` and it will work as you want:

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
b = np.array([[True], [False], [True]])

c = a[b.ravel()]
```

which gives `c` as:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```